# how to play o flash movie in application

Tags: android, flash

I want to create very simple application with 2 view:
-> list with some tags
-> single view with movie

every tag is connected to a flash movie. The movie will be on my own server in web. I want to play in my app this movie with a some player. But not via web browser but inside my application. is that possible ? What do I need to do to achive that ? I mean how to play the movie. Building list etc is easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use web view with the following settings:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

To make sure flash is installed use:

```
    public boolean isFlashAvailable() {
    try {
        String mVersion = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ADOBE_FLASH_PLAYER_PACKAGE_NAME, 0).versionName;
        //Log.d("Flash", "Installed: " + mVersion);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        //Log.d("Flash", "Not installed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could WebView to play some HTML which uses a flash.